# Using Pidgin with OTR-encryption on Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, encryption, pidgin

Please show here how to install and activate OTR ("Off-The-Record") and Pidgin to me on both: Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

**How to setup pidgin with off the record support in Linux/Fedora 17:**

1. Install Operating System Fedora 17.
2. Install pidgin with `yum install pidgin`
3. Install otr with `yum install pidgin-otr`
4. Start pidgin.
5. Click tools -> Plugins.
6. Put a checkmark in Off-the-Record Messaging 3.2.1.
7. Click Configure Plugin.
8. Pick your account.
9. Generate the key.
10. Have your friend send you an OTR message.  Normally you get this:

    (04:16:14 PM) otheruser@something.com: ?OTRv23? otheruser@something.com/Home has requested an Off-the-Record private conversation. However, you do not have a plugin to support that. See http://otr.cypherpunks.ca/ for more information.
11. You will have to follow some onscreen directions and coordinate with your buddy to exchange fingerprints.
12. [Pick up that can citizen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNd8iNx1gGk)... The can of tyranny is thus kicked down the road another 50 yards with an illegal application of privacy.

Comment: To speed up step "9. Generate the key." you can `yum install haveged` which gives you more randomness so the key generation speeds up 100th times as fast! Otherwise that step can take several minutes

Answer (score 1):

From the author:

- On Linux: 
  there is the package `pidgin-otr` to be installed
- On Windows: you have to download the **Win32 installer for pidgin from http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/**

You can create a new user on your first login, just create a Jabber **"XMPP"-Account** use a new username and one of the [free jabber-domain of your choice](http://xmpp.net/) (for example: "jabber.ccc.de") and check the box at the bottom in the registration page to crate that user now.

In your contactlist you have to activate the "Off-The-Record Messaging" Plugin under (german): "Werkzeuge"->"Erweiterungen". Activate it and click configure to [enable logging of encrypted chat](https://superuser.com/a/620525/160420), if desired. (be aware that it is good manners to inform the other side in chat, that you enabled logging)

here is a complete installation instruction with pictures:
https://securityinabox.org/en/using_pidgin (but that is really cluttered with a lot too much to read.)

I would like to have this HowTo in one place (with only some few screenshots), so I can send the link to someone new for a quick start.

Here you find a [A German HowTo](http://www.x-fish.org/blog/120131/Pidgin_Portable_und_OTR_%E2%80%93_verschl%C3%BCsselt_chatten/).

Comment: please add the package `haveged` to speed up the key generation.