# Activate local logging of OTR chat sessions in Pidgin

Tags: encryption, logging, pidgin, chat

I am [Using Pidgin with OTR-encryption on Linux and Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/604376/using-pidgin-with-otr-encryption-on-linux-and-windows?rq=1) but those encrypted chats are not logged in my chat history.

Is it possible to activate the chatlog for chats, that are done with OTR-encryption?

Comment: just something to think about: thats kinda the point of OTR. the other party in the conversation would likely be livid that you had logged the messages, since they trusted you enough to have an OTR chat with you.

Comment: that's not the point, I could store my chat logs in a secure place. or the other side could get a message, that I am logging the chat. (I could do it manually anyway with a lot of copy and paste)

Comment: I suggested to the maintainer to inform the chatpartner, that the secure session is logged on the other chatpartner side:  http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=717097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in the settings of the OTR-Plugin to enable logging called 
"Don't log OTR conversations":
[image]

or in german:

[image]